# Is there a limit to the number of nested #call:'s in Seaside?

Tags: pharo, seaside, pharo-6

I'm developing a Seaside Application and I suspect I've reached a point in which I can no longer `#call:` another component.
It's not an issue of my WAComponents, since I tried other messages that end up in `#call:`, like  `#confirm:`.

I have 4 nested `#call:`'s in my app (I know, I know... but I'm not looking for design advice, just an answer on this :) ). The 5th just reloads the page, and the called component never appears.

I searched the docs but there's nothing about this, and debugging is really difficult to me, since I'm not familiar with Seaside's inner code.

This is Seaside 3.2 under Pharo 6.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a small example to reconstruct it? This should not happen. There is no such limit.

Comment: Thanks! Considering what you said (there shouldn't be a limit), I've been experimenting further and maybe I didn't do a good job in isolating the cause. Will get back with the simplest scenario I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the nested `#call:`s, as correctly indicated in Johan's comment.

In this particular case, the "null" behavior of `#call:` (i.e., just reloading the page), was due to an error in the `#children` method of the parent `WAComponent`.  What was happening here was:

- Component **A** `#render:`'ed component **B**, but component **A**'s `#children:` was buggy
- Component **B** wanted to `#call:` component **C**
- The `#call:` didn't work, it just reloaded the page

As the [Seaside documentation](http://www.seaside.st/documentation/subcomponents) states, every `WAComponent` that renders another `WAComponent` **must** redefine `#children` with a collection of all subcomponents. It's easy to forget to implement to do this, since most of the times it's not a show-stopper. Until you find yourself into this kind of scenario.